# MIPS: Append to text file

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I need to append a string to a text file. Is there a way to open the file for append in MIPS, (I use Mars simulator) ? And if it it what flag should I use, I presume that should be 4 but it doesn't work and I cannot find a list of available flags for service 13 anywhere ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot find a list of available flags for service 13 anywhere

They're listed [here](http://courses.missouristate.edu/kenvollmar/mars/help/syscallhelp.html). According to that page *"MARS implements three flag values: 0 for read-only, 1 for write-only with create, and **9 for write-only with create and append**. "*

Comment: Thanks, I was looking on this page many times but I don't know why I didn't saw it.